# BX slider on mobile device starting from 1st slide. I want it to start from the last slide on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using `BX SLIDER` for a website. I want it to start from the last `slider` on page load.
Here is my code:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
pagerCustom: '.bx-pager',
auto:false,
    startSlide: 0,
    randomStart: false,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: false,
    responsive: true,
    touchEnabled: true,
    controls: true,
    nextText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TZDsPC0.png" height="25" width="25"/>',
    prevText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AKjTWvT.png" height="25" width="25"/>',

    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,


});
```

I did some research but I couldn't find anything. Kindly help me how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `startSlide`?

Comment: `startSlide: $('.bxslider div').length - 1` should work